# Jenkins on Kubernetes service yaml parsing error

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-cluster

I'm following this [Link](https://digitalavenue.dev/How-To-Setup-Jenkins-On-Kubernetes/) to setup `Jenkins` on `Kubernetes` cluster. When I tried to apply `jenkins-svc.yaml` it fails with an error.

`jenkins-svc.yaml` file content as follows,

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ui-service
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
    type: ClusterIP # NodePort, LoadBalancer 
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      # nodePort: 30100
      name: ui
  selector:
    app: jenkins
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-jnlp-service
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
    type: ClusterIP # NodePort, LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 50000
      targetPort: 50000
  selector:
    app: jenkins
```

The error I get when I tried to apply `jenkins-svc.yaml`.

```
# kubectl  apply -f jenkins-svc.yaml -n jenkins
error: error parsing jenkins-svc.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 7: did not find expected key
```

Please let me know how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check indentation of line 7 & 23. remove 2 extra spaces before "type" in spec section for both svc.

Comment: Thanks Anurag, I was trying to adjust line number `7` and below lines as per line no `23` and its sub lines.